# Profile does not appear to be used

Tags: powershell

I have created all six (6) profile scripts for PowerShell. Each has a simple one-liner to write out its purpose.

```
PS C:\src\t> .\psprofiles.ps1
=== Current User PowerShell Console
$HOME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
C:\Users\lit\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
Write-Host "Current user, console"
=== Current User PowerShell ISE
$HOME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
C:\Users\lit\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
Write-Host "Current user, ISE"
=== Current User All Hosts
$home\Documents\profile.ps1
C:\Users\lit\Documents\profile.ps1
Write-Host "Current user, all hosts"
=== All Users PowerShell Console
$pshome\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
Write-Host "All users, console"
=== All Users PowerShell ISE
$pshome\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
Write-Host "All users, ISE"
=== All Users All Hosts
$pshome\profile.ps1
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
Write-Host "All users, all hosts"
```

When I start a console, the profile for `Current user, all hosts` does not appear to be invoked. Why does `Current user, all hosts` not appear to be invoked?

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

All users, all hosts
All users, console
Current user, console
PS C:\Users\lit>
```

In a similar way, when I start the ISE the `Current user, all hosts` is not invoked. However, `Current user, console` is invoked. Why is this?

```
All users, all hosts
All users, ISE
Current user, console
Current user, ISE
PS C:\Users\lit>
```

I am using:

```
PS C:\Users\lit> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion on Windows 10.

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  1066
```

I see that these `NoteProperty` items are attached to $PROFILE.

```
PS C:\src\t> $PROFILE | Format-List -Force    

AllUsersAllHosts       : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
AllUsersCurrentHost    : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
CurrentUserAllHosts    : C:\Users\pwatson\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
CurrentUserCurrentHost : C:\Users\pwatson\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
Length                 : 77
```

After replacing the output in each profile script with the above names, it appears as expected

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

AllUsersAllHosts
AllUsersCurrentHost
CurrentUserAllHosts
CurrentUserCurrentHost
```

And when starting the ISE:

```
AllUsersAllHosts
AllUsersCurrentHost ISE
CurrentUserAllHosts
CurrentUserCurrentHost ISE
PS C:\Users\lit>
```

Comment: Run this `$PROFILE|fl * -Force` and recheck which is which profile.

Comment: When I went back to change the names to the NoteProperty values, it appeared that one of the files did not exist. However, the script above suggests that it did. I will edit the question to include what I get now. Many thanks, @PetSerAl.